# Bash/shell search for subfolder in current dir and cd into it

Tags: bash

How would I go about search if the folder "test" is anywhere within my current dir and once the first occurrence is found automatically cd into it? Using the terminal on mac (bash).

Comment: `cd test` ? Or do you mean `test` could be in some other subdir of `.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will work if that dir exists ->

```
cd `find . -name test -type d`
```

For bash I guess below should work ->

```
cd $(find . -name test -type d)
```

Comment: This will misbehave if there are multiple occurrences of `test`. (The OP specified that (s)he wanted "the first occurrence".) It will also misbehave if there are any whitespace characters or asterisks or whatnot in the path to `test`.

Comment: @ruakh agreed, so will "-quit" take care of first occurance?

Comment: -1 simple because this is an wrong solution. Will fail a.) when exists multiple `test` dirs, b.) will fail if here isn't `test` directory, will `cd $HOME`.

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

```
cd "$(find . -type d -name test -print -quit)"
```

(Caveat: this works for `test`, but will not work for any filename ending in newlines. Fortunately, I've never heard of anyone having a *real* filename that ended in a newline — it's possible, but never done — and the filename is an argument under your control. So I can't imagine that this will be a problem.)

Comment: Thanks, but this produces an error for me. It hast to do with this part `-print -quit` since it works fine without it.

Comment: @LukasOppermann: What is the error that it produces? (Sorry: I should have mentioned that I only tested this with GNU Find, because I don't have a Mac handy.)

Comment: My bad, the missing "." seems to be the error.  
**find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
** This works fine cd "$(find . -type d -name test -print -quit)"

Comment: on the mac you need specify the path, so can't use `find -type...` (default `.`) but **must** `find . -type...`

Comment: @jm666: Thanks, both of you. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `globstar` option of bash which searches directories recursively.

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*test; do 
    if [[ -d $i ]]; then
        cd "$i"
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
if [ -d "test" ]; then cd test; fi
```

Or simply :

```
[ -d "test" ] && cd test
```

Comment: This will not work if that directory is not an immediate sub-dir

Comment: read the question well. OP is asking `if the folder "test" is anywhere within my current dir` !

Comment: Yes I read it. Current dir may have sub-directories and those sub-directories may have further sub-directories. In those case, all those directories becomes part of current dir :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I missed the word `anywhere`. Updating the answer soon. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Or just do ...

```
cd test
```

... if `test` is a directory the you just `cd'ed` into it.
If is not ... so what.